# unrecognized 'configure' option `--enable-executable-profiling'

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

After upgrading from ghc 7.8.3 to ghc 7.8.4, I did a `cabal update`, and saw that there was a new version of cabal. So I ran the command

```
cabal --no-require-sandbox install cabal-install
```

and got the error message

```
unrecognized 'configure' option `--enable-executable-profiling'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `executable-profiling` appears to have been renamed to `profiling` at some point. There are some other changes to the configuration parameters as well. I suspect that all I needed to do was change `executable-profiling` to `profiling` in `~/.cabal/config` and re-try my cabal install.

However, I didn't know *a priori* what the changes were. So my solution* was:

1. `mv ~/.cabal/config ~/.cabal/config.BACKUP`
2. `cabal update` to create a new default configuration file.
3. Edit `~/.cabal/config` to preserve any settings from `~/.cabal/config.BACKUP` I wanted to keep for the next step, BUT NOT `executable-profiling`.
4. `cabal --no-require-sandbox install cabal-install`
5. `rm ~/.cabal/config`
6. `cabal update` to create a new default configuration file. As soon as a new default configuration file has been created, you can CTRL-c.
7. Edit `~/.cabal/config` to preserve any settings from `~/.cabal/config.BACKUP` I wanted to keep going forward.

---

**EDIT:** *I've just discovered the cabal command `user-config`, which seems tailor-made for situations like this. To learn more, type `cabal help user-config`.